# Azure AD b2c android app to access non-Graph API securely

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to access an API on the same server that my android app is registered. The process of logging into the android app works fine. I have attempted to use the IAuthenticationResult.getAccessToken() generated to access an API on the same server unsuccessfully. I get a 401 Unauthorized error message both on Postman and my application. The sample applications available work fine with Microsoft Graph but I haven't seen any sample accessing other forms of API including those hosted in the same client.

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide a screenshot, check `aud` to make sure it is the api you want to call.

Comment: The aud shown in jwt.ms is the correct clientid. But take note the the clientid in this case is for the webapp against which the android app has been registered. The APIs are endpoints exposed by the webapp. The way I am accessing the API is by decorating the target API with [Authorize] and passing a bearer token (i.e. IAuthenticationResult.getAccessToken() ) from the android application

Comment: Have you expose  the api protected by Azure?

Comment: How did you get the token? Is it convenient to provide postman screenshots?

Comment: On your first question, I had mentioned that the same webapp that I have registered is also exposing several end points (about 35) which the android application front end interacts with. On the second question, the token is from the authentication results (i.e. authenticationResult.getAccessToken()) of the com.microsoft.identity.client.AuthenticationCallback. The code snippet for the callback portion is private AuthenticationCallback getAuthInteractiveCallback() {  @Override
            public void onSuccess(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) { authenticationResult.getAccessToken()

Comment: sorry, for some reason there is no button for uploading an image or pasting an image with shortcut keys in my case. Unless I am missing something or it is my stackoverflow account profile settings

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are still looking for help

Comment: Thanks, I  don't need help on this. I managed to get the solution by specify the scope parameter in android as {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};. I will capture it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is specifying the SCOPE parameter in the android code as {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};. That was the only way I could obtain a valid bearer token that could be validated on the backend by calling https://jwt.ms/